# How to track leaking Gradle API dependency

Tags: gradle

There is an `application` Gradle plugin in `build.gradle.kts`, configured as usual:

```
plugins {
//...
  application
//...
}

application {
  mainClassName = "org.myapp.ApplicationKt"  
}
```

Unusual is that after running `gradlew install`, Gradle API dependency leaks into resulting artifact:

```
$ ls -lSrh myapp/build/install/myapp/lib
...
-rw-rw-r-- 1 8.1M Oct 17 20:53 groovy-all-1.3-2.5.12.jar
-rw-rw-r-- 1  12M Oct 17 20:53 elasticsearch-7.6.2.jar
-rw-rw-r-- 1  22M Oct 17 20:53 pulsar-client-2.4.0.jar
-rw-rw-r-- 1 137M Oct 17 20:53 gradle-api-6.6.1.jar
```

It is about 150M extra in libraries! At the same time there is neither gradleApi() dependency in `gradlew :myapp:dependencies` nor in task's Build Scan. Yet running `gradlew :myapp:install --debug` clearly shows that yes, Gradle API dependencies are resolved in `runtimeClasspath`:

```
2020-10-17T20:55:38.653+0700 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Execute copy for :myapp:installDist' started
2020-10-17T20:55:38.654+0700 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DirectoryFileTree] file or directory '/home/user/project_repo.git/myapp/src/main/dist', not found
2020-10-17T20:55:38.654+0700 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.DirectoryFileTree] file or directory '/home/user/project_repo.git/myapp/src/dist', not found
2020-10-17T20:55:38.654+0700 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Resolve files of :myapp:runtimeClasspath' started
2020-10-17T20:55:38.654+0700 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.component.model.LoggingAttributeMatchingExplanationBuilder] Selected match gradle-api-6.6.1.jar (Gradle API) from candidates [gradle-api-6.6.1.jar (Gradle API)] for {org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.jvm.version=8, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime, org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type=jvm}
2020-10-17T20:55:38.654+0700 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.component.model.LoggingAttributeMatchingExplanationBuilder] Selected match groovy-all-1.3-2.5.12.jar (Gradle API) from candidates [groovy-all-1.3-2.5.12.jar (Gradle API)] for {org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.jvm.version=8, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime, org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type=jvm}
2020-10-17T20:55:38.654+0700 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.component.model.LoggingAttributeMatchingExplanationBuilder] Selected match kotlin-stdlib-1.3.72.jar (Gradle API) from candidates [kotlin-stdlib-1.3.72.jar (Gradle API)] for {org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.jvm.version=8, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime, org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type=jvm}
2020-10-17T20:55:38.654+0700 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.component.model.LoggingAttributeMatchingExplanationBuilder] Selected match kotlin-stdlib-common-1.3.72.jar (Gradle API) from candidates [kotlin-stdlib-common-1.3.72.jar (Gradle API)] for {org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.jvm.version=8, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime, org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type=jvm}
2020-10-17T20:55:38.654+0700 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.component.model.LoggingAttributeMatchingExplanationBuilder] Selected match kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.3.72.jar (Gradle API) from candidates [kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.3.72.jar (Gradle API)] for {org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.jvm.version=8, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime, org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type=jvm}
2020-10-17T20:55:38.655+0700 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.component.model.LoggingAttributeMatchingExplanationBuilder] Selected match kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.3.72.jar (Gradle API) from candidates [kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.3.72.jar (Gradle API)] for {org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.jvm.version=8, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime, org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type=jvm}
2020-10-17T20:55:38.655+0700 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.component.model.LoggingAttributeMatchingExplanationBuilder] Selected match kotlin-reflect-1.3.72.jar (Gradle API) from candidates [kotlin-reflect-1.3.72.jar (Gradle API)] for {org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.jvm.version=8, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime, org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type=jvm}
2020-10-17T20:55:38.655+0700 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.component.model.LoggingAttributeMatchingExplanationBuilder] Selected match gradle-installation-beacon-6.6.1.jar (Gradle API) from candidates [gradle-installation-beacon-6.6.1.jar (Gradle API)] for {org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.jvm.version=8, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime, org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type=jvm}
2020-10-17T20:55:38.655+0700 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Completing Build operation 'Resolve files of :myapp:runtimeClasspath'
2020-10-17T20:55:38.655+0700 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Resolve files of :myapp:runtimeClasspath' completed
```

How to track the leaking depencency?

Comment: strange indeed.. did you try  `./gradlew :myapp:dependencies` to analyse dependencies graph? this could help locating which library is "bringing" Gradle API libs into the runtime classpath.

Comment: Yes I did `:myapp:dependencies` too -- no sign of Gradle API in it's output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is `kotlin-dsl` plugin configured explicitely for the module:

```
plugins {
    // ...
    id("org.gradle.kotlin.kotlin-dsl")
    // ...
}
```

Once it is commented out, the problem is gone.